# How to use move object by tilting for android on Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D racing game for Android. I can move my car left and right by touch with the given code. But I want to do it by tilting my phone left and right by hand. How can i do that?

```
public void carSpeed = 10.0f;
void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        if(touch.position.x < Screen.width/2){
            transform.position += Vector3.left * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


        }
        else if(touch.position.x > Screen.width/2){
            transform.position += Vector3.right * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        }
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);
        transform.position = position;

    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Input.acceleration Here are a couple links that can help you learn how to use the accelerometer. Note that you will not be able to use the accelerometer controls in the Unity editor. You will have to test the controls on a mobile device (at least to my knowledge). Also try Andrew's response above.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24543/using-the-accelerometer-to-move-left-and-right-on.html

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/accelerometer-input

Comment: no problem! I'm happy that I could help. why the downvote though? :(

Comment: Thanks again for ur help but i'm sorry for the down vote. :( Maybe somebody did that. Why i'm going to give u downvote in case of your helping support? :(

Comment: yeah, it's fine. Glad I could help though!

Answer (score 0):

something like this (pseudo code)

```
public void carSpeed = 10.0f;
void Update() {
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
    dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
    dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;
    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        dir.Normalize();

    dir *= Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 position = transform.position += (dir * carSpeed);
    position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But it actually didn't work. The car goes here and there. :( Specially right side of the screen. Should i use Vector2 variable as i want to control my car only left and right side?

Comment: What do u mean by "goes here and there"? And what do u mean my specially right side of screen?

Comment: Actually i mean that when i test by my android device, the car is turn right automatically. I can't control it by tilting my device. :(

Comment: well your device is always giving out acceleration probably, or its from the way you are holding it. try to debug a baseline acceleration reading, then use that as an offset.